# What does this mean in Python? arr[stack.pop()] = i

Tags: python, stack

I stumbled upon this line of code and trying to understand what rightspval[stack.pop()] = i, mean?

```
        for i in range(1,n):
        while stack and A[stack[-1]] < A[i]:
            rightspval[stack.pop()] = i
        stack.append(i)
```

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

stack is a list that appears to be being used as a lifo stack.  the pop removes an entry from it and returns it as the rightspval index (either a key in a dictionary or index in an array)  whatever element is referred to is set with the value of I.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context on the content of `A` and `stack`, it's hard to say what this algorithm is about.

However, the operation `rightspval[stack.pop()]` can be explained.

- For any list `a`, `a[x]` is the `x`th cell of `a`, with indexing starting at 0;
- For any list `s`, `s.pop()` **removes and returns** the last element of `s`;
- `a[s.pop()] = ...` is equivalent to `x=s.pop(); a[x] = ...`.

Here is an example of `.pop` in action:

```py
s = [10,11,12,13]
print(s)
# [10, 11, 12, 13]
print(s.pop())
# 13
print(s)
# [10, 11, 12]
```

And now, an example combining `a[ ]` and `s.pop()`:

```py
a = [100 + i for i in range(20)]
s = [10, 11, 12, 13]
print(a)
# [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
print(s)
# [10, 11, 12, 13]
a[s.pop()] = 'wouhou'
print(a)
# [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 'wouhou', 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
print(s)
# [10, 11, 12]
```

Since the last element of `s` was `13`, those two lines are equivalent:

```py
a[s.pop()] = 'wouhou'
s.pop(); a[13] = 'wouhou'
```

***Small note:** In this explanation, I assumed `a` and `s` were both lists. Actually, `a` can be any object that supports the `[ ]` operation, for instance a list, a string, or a dictionary.*